# Lowest Spec VPS to run Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vps

I want to get started with my first Ruby on Rails application.

It will pull an image, and some text about the image display both, and have a small box to write some text about the image, which will then be written to a database once submitted.

It's unlikely to have any more than 5 concurrent users, as it's a personal project.

What's the lowest VPS spec needed to run ruby on rails? Would it be possible on 64mb (128 burst) ram or could I go even lower?

Comment: Where on earth are you even finding a VPS with only 64MB of RAM?! That's doesn't even meet the system requirements for Ubuntu Server.

Comment: I had a VERY small rails deployed at Joyent on what they used to call a 1/4 GB machine, 256 MB, BARELY enough,  that thing that forced me to move to 1GB was that there were some GEMS that wouldn't build with only 256MB.  I'd say 256MB is the bare minimum,  and if you needed to build a large GEM, 512 MB.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall

They go down to 32mb: http://securedragon.net/index.php?p=openvz

Comment: @Joseph Yea those would definitely not work. You're better off with a free Heroku account than anything with that little RAM. Also I'd be *very* suspicious of that host's unusually low prices, as that's usually not a good sign.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Ah the pricing page wasn't explicit about providing free stuff. I still don't really understand how heroku works.

If I need to store all these images (approx 100 jpegs) do I have to host them with my other host? Or do I have to start paying for overkill database storage?

Comment: @Joseph Yup, and usually that place is Amazon S3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The lowest I'd advocate is a 512MB system. The Ruby on Rails stack can be 50-100MB alone unless you're very careful about pruning off extras. This is an inconsequential amount of memory on a modern system, though, where 4096MB is common even in the VPS world.

[Linode](http://linode.com/) offers a $19.95 plan for the basic 512MB system which, while not the cheapest around, is very affordable even for personal projects. There are less expensive providers, but their quality of service may vary considerably.

If you're using [Passenger](http://modrails.com/) then even a 512MB machine can run several lightly loaded sites.

Instead of running your own VPS you might want to use [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) which doesn't allocate memory to customers directly but instead shares of CPU time they call "Dynos" that are somewhat more abstract than a VPS.

Comment: May I ask what's so special about Passenger that it use less memory?

Answer (score 8):

Younger Joseph. You should've learn to use git and started using Heroku. [Heroku](http://heroku.com) doesn't publicize it clearly on the website but they offer a free plan.

Comment: No more free plan https://help.heroku.com/RSBRUH58/removal-of-heroku-free-product-plans-faq